# Entry into the database without reloading the page - No route matches [POST] "/contacts"

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I want to make an entry in the database on the user's posts without reloading the page. But at the touch does not find a route.

let_controller.rb

```
class LetController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :js

  def index
  end

  def contacts
    @contacts = Question.new
  end


  def language
    session[:language] = params[:language][0..1]
    set_language
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def new
    @contacts = Question.new
  end

  def create
    @contacts = Question.new(question_params)
    @contacts.request = request
  end

  private

  def question_params

    params.require(:questions).permit(:name, :e_mail, :phone, :text_q )

  end
end
```

contacts.html.erb

```
<div id="main-block">

    <%= render 'contact_form' %>
</div>
```

_contact_form.html.erb

```
 <ul class="errors"></ul>
   <%= form_for @contacts , :remote => true  do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_field :name , placeholder: "Имя" %> <br>
        <%= f.text_field :e_mail, placeholder: "e-mail" %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :phone, placeholder: "Телефон" %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :text_q, placeholder: "Сообщение" %><br>
     <%= f.submit "Задать вопрос", class: "btn btn-primary"%>
    <% end %>
```

save.js.erb

```
$("ul.errors").html("")
<% if @contacts.errors.any? %>
<% @contacts.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
$("ul.errors").append($("<li />").html("<%= message.html_safe %>"))
<% end %>
<% else %>
$("#main-block").empty()
$("#main-block").html("Сообщение отправлено!")
<% end %>
```

create.js.erb

```
<%= render 'save' %>
```

new.js.erb

```
$("#main-block").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'contact_form') %>")
```

routes.rb

```
 resources :let

  root 'let#index'
  match '/index', to: 'let#index', via: 'get'
  match '/contacts', to: 'let#contacts', via: 'get'
  post '/let/contacts', as: 'contacts'
```

terminal loading page

```
Started GET "/contacts" for ::1 at 2016-06-14 15:04:57 +0300
Processing by LetController#contacts as HTML
  Rendered let/_contact_form.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered let/contacts.html.erb within layouts/application (2.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (4.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 70ms (Views: 69.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

terminal before click button submit

```
Started POST "/contacts" for ::1 at 2016-06-14 15:08:18 +0300

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/contacts"):
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /Users/os/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/os/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/os/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refactor your routes to something like

```
resources :let do
  collection do
    get 'contacts', to 'let#contacts'
    post 'contacts', to 'let#create', as: :create_contacts
  end
end

root 'let#index'
```

and change the url in the form

```
<%= form_for @contacts, url: { action: :create }, remote: true  do |f| %>
```

Comment: ``add_route': Invalid route name, already in use: 'contacts'  (ArgumentError)
You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources` as explained here: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created
`... If I remove the line  post '/let/contacts', as: 'contacts' the previous error

Comment: undefined local variable or method `create_contacts_path' for #<#<Class:0x007ffee1be7c28>:0x007ffee238c5f0> =(

Comment: Please try `<%= form_for @contacts, url: { action: :create }, remote: true  do |f| %>`